# Каково значение и происхождение выражения "ни шатко ни валко"?

Tags: этимология, фразеология

Из словаря:

**Ни шатко ни валко (ни на сторону).**
**Ирон.** Ни хорошо, ни плохо; не лучшим образом. И таким образом дело продолжало идти, как говорится, **ни шатко ни валко ни на сторону** (Салтыков-Щедрин. Помпадуры и помпадурши). [https://phraseology.academic.ru/14126/Ни_шатко_ни_валко_%28ни_на_сторону%29](https://phraseology.academic.ru/14126/%D0%9D%D0%B8_%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BE_%D0%BD%D0%B8_%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%BE_%28%D0%BD%D0%B8_%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%83%29)

**Вопросы:**

**1) О значении фразеологизма**

Какой синоним ближе по значению: а) ни то ни сё, посредственно; б) обыкновенно; в) ни быстро ни медленно; г) ни хорошо ни плохо; д) не очень хорошо.

Это всегда ироничное выражение? Насколько оно современно и менялось ли его значение?

Сравнить: Устар. Экспрес. Хуже не может быть, не бывает; очень плохо. — А, здравствуй, Иван Панкратович!.. Как поживаешь?.. — Ох, плохо, отец, плохо! **и шатко и валко и на сторону** (Григорович. Просёлочные дороги).

Кстати, эта форма фразеологизма кажется **более логичной** (соединительный союз И...И).

**2)  О происхождении фразеологизма**

Часто такого рода выражения построены с участием антонимов, но здесь **шатко и валко** ― не антонимы. А что связывает эти слова? И что означает эта добавка ― **ни на сторону?**

**3) Пунктуация**

Запятые вроде бы не нужны, но их почему-то часто ставят. Это допускается? Нужны ли запятые в полном варианте?

4) Что можно сказать **об этой статье** на тему происхождения фразеологизма? http://www.leaks.ru/history/ni-shatko-ni-valko.html

Примеры:

Работа шла **ни шатко ни валко**, все поглядывали на часы. [Сергей Лукьяненко. Новогодний Дозор (2014)]

Все в нем было как-то **вразброд, неустойчиво, ни шатко ни валко**. [Влада Валеева. Скорая помощь (2002)]

На некотором расстоянии от них, **так же ни шатко, ни валко,** двигалась темно-синяя «пятерка». [Петр Галицкий. Цена Шагала (2000)]

**Ни шатко, ни валко, ни на сторону.** [А. В. Амфитеатров. Курортный муж (из сборника «Бабы и дамы») (1893)]

**Все у нас ни шатко, ни валко.** [В. Г. Короленко. Письма (1900)]